# How can I return to a specific activity that has already been created previously?

Tags: android, timer

My end goal is this:
MainActivity has a button that starts SubActivity (which is essentially a timer).
Each time the button is pressed a new SubActivity starts.
MainActivity also has a RecyclerView that displays a card for each SubActivity so that you may return to any timer that you have already started.

My problem is I don't know how to return to each Activity. I already did some research, and most people point towards onSaveInstanceState, but from my understanding that simply would recreate the activity by saving values and restoring them. I know my timer SubActivities still proceed in the background because even when I leave the SubActivity with the timer running, the alarm will go off later, but I am left unable to reopen that activity in the meanwhile.

So how do I access the running timer activity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you want to achieve really, but it looks like wrong app design. If you want timer to run regardless of activity then you should decouple timer from activity and make activity just display the timer. Your timers should be elsewhere and definitely its lifecycle should not depend of actvity lifecycle.

Comment: I took your advice, and separated the timer class from my 2nd activity which displays the timer. Sorry that I was lazy earlier even though I knew i should follow OOP. Thank you.

However, i am still left unsure of where to go next, I still need to access the timers that I have already started from my main activity?

Comment: Sure, but but since you got timers decoupled you should assign each timer unique Id. the timer container (what is `timer` thing in your case really?) that manages these could allow obtaining the timer (or it's value i.e. with method like `getTimer(timerId);` or so.